# Good style - return enum or int?

Tags: c++, coding-style, enums

If I have a class that defines an enum, should a member function that returns that enum be declared as returning that enum, or as returning an int?

For example:

```
class Foo {

  public:

    enum Stooge { larry, moe, curly};

    Stooge WhoToPoke();
    // OR: int WhoToPoke(); ???

}
```

I've been declaring such a method as returning the enum, but didn't know if it was 'better style' or somehow more useable for a client if I declare it as int.

Comment: I'd go with the enum. Still, I don't think this question is suitable for [so].

Comment: a memberfunction that returns an X should not be declared returning an Y. Exceptions are generalizations like pointers to base classes.

Comment: All classis in the standard library go for the enum eg ios::out. Can't beat that.

Comment: I would also suggest looking @ )[Type Safe Enum Idiom](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Type_Safe_Enum) - I use this together with a static boost bimap for serialization/deserialization

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `enum` provides some type safety for the caller... for example, they can not pass an `int` as a parameter when an `Foo::Stooge` is expected, or initialise a Foo::Stooge with an (uncast) `int` or an `enum` of another type.

BobTFish's comment correctly points out that there's still lots of nasty code that does compile - more than I remembered as I don't try to write bad code to keep probing the edges of compiler checks!  C++11 improves on this for `enum class`es.

Further, if you add say a `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, Stooge)` function, then they could stream the value - the implementation could guarantee a symbolic name (i.e. they'd actually see "larry", "moe" or "curly" in the stream).

Comment: "The `enum` provides type safety for the caller..." Not true. That's why we now have `enum class`. See https://ideone.com/q7d83T

Comment: @BoBTFish I can't make sense of your link, what do you mean?

Comment: @BoBTFish: Scoped enumerations do indeed give stronger type safety; but unscoped enumerations still give some type safety (compared with integer types), as the answer describes.

Comment: My example shows that you both *can* compare it to some other unrelated value, and *can* pass it when an `int` is expected.

Comment: So in other words, an enum doesn't give perfect type safety (an implicit conversion to an int still happens), but provides some safety (e.g. comparison of different enums isn't allowed). Since you want to communicate this typing, you shouldn't use an int return value.

Comment: @BobTFish: yikes - didn't remember that it was still that loose.  I've added some hopefully correct examples of type safety checks it does enforce....